# Breaking SQL UPDATE SET to two separate queries for getting the data and updating it

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query is doing `UPDATE SET` on two tables in parallel, the result of it is the number of updated rows.

```
String updateSql =  "UPDATE table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2 " +
                    "SET tbl1.status=:status, tbl2.status=:status " +
                    "WHERE ...;


return entityManager.createNativeQuery(updateSql)
                    .setParameter("status", SomeStatus.NEW).
                    .executeUpdate();
```

I want to be able to track which rows exactly are updated (for example, `tbl1.id`).
For this, as I understand, I need to break this query into two queries - the first will return the data, as collection, and the second will do the actual update.

How to do this in the most effective way?

Comment: You should include the entire query, because it is relevant to the question you asked.  That being said, you may just do a select with the same join and filtering logic to find out which IDs would be targeted.

Comment: MySQL cannot return or identify updated rows. You must execute according SELECT firstly (and retrieve the rows to be updated) then update.

Comment: PS. Updating 2 independent tables in one query is more expensive on the MySQL side then two separate updates.

Comment: @Akina thanks. As for - "Updating 2 independent tables in one query are more expensive on the MySQL side than two separate updates", could you please provide something to read about it? Wasn't familiar with that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's a bit business-related, so I've tried to avoid it. Just to understand the general approach.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will find "something to read" about what no one does. Except for very rare special cases.

Comment: The closing votes are kinda strange for me here, because your answer DID HELP ME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested here, I separated the one query into separate 3:

1. Getting the list of elements I need to update (by index).
2. Updating table 1.
3. Updating table 2.